# Есть ли возможность отключить exception?

Tags: php, yii2

Пытаюсь написать парсер для этого использую класс Snoopy.class   на некоторые страницы (не на все) выдает вот такой exception.

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException fsockopen():

Проверил вне yii скрипт выдал предупреждение такого характера.

> **Warning**:  fsockopen():  in **C:\OpenServer\domains\kinopoisk\Snoopy.class.php** on line
>   **1142**

но скрипт отработался (более или менее  но нужную информацию получил)
Вопрос можно как то  в сделать так, yii2,  что бы   случае предупреждения скрипт все же продолжил работу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может вам поможет вызвать функцию с @:

```
@fsockopen();
```

Comment: Это хороший способ, если есть желание побыть Малдером и словить необъяснимые глюки (которые не были бы таковыми, не подавляй сообщения о ошибке).